# AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

when I test this view

```
@action(methods=['GET'], detail=True)
    def nearby(self, request, pk=None):
        """get nearby energy resources to
        the current energy resource in detail"""
        energy_resource = self.get_object()
        energy_resources = EnergyResource.objects.annotate(
            distance=Distance('location', energy_resource.location)
        ).order_by('distance')[0:3]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(energy_resources, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

with this test

```
def test_retrieve_nearby_energy_resources(self):
        """Test getting a list of three nearby energy resources"""
        test_user2 = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='test2', password='test2password')
        r = sample_resource(self.user, 5, 5)
        sample_resource(test_user2, 4, 5)
        sample_resource(test_user2, 5, 4)
        sample_resource(test_user2, 5, 3)
        r4 = sample_resource(test_user2, 25, 63)
        url = reverse('energy-resource-nearby',
                      args=[r.id])

        response = self.client.get(url)
        resources_nearby = EnergyResource.objects.exclude(id=r4.id).order_by()
        resource_not_nearby = EnergyResource.objects.get(id=r4.id)
        serializer_nearby = EnergyResourceSerializer(
            resources_nearby, many=True)
        serializer_not_nearby = EnergyResourceSerializer(resource_not_nearby)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertContains(response.data, serializer_nearby.data)
        self.assertNotContains(response.data, serializer_not_nearby)
```

it returns

```
ERROR: test_retrieve_nearby_energy_resources (energy_resources.tests.test_views.EnergyResourcePrivateAPITests)
Test getting a list of three nearby energy resources
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/energy_resources/tests/test_views.py", line 210, in test_retrieve_nearby_energy_resources
    self.assertContains(response.data, serializer_nearby.data)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/workspace-dqq3IVyd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 445, in assertContains
    text_repr, real_count, msg_prefix = self._assert_contains(
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/workspace-dqq3IVyd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 416, in _assert_contains
    response.status_code, status_code,
AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'status_code'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 12 tests in 2.250s
```

it works in broswer and if I commented out assertContain and assertNotContain the test passes so it meants the response has status code attribute, right? what is different about assertContain and assertNotContain?

Comment: Are you using `APIClient` to test, or some other client?  Also, on the first failure the test stops, the the next 2 lines that you commented out never get run.

Comment: @AndrewBacker yes i use APIClient and that's why it's weird behavior i am asking about, how can assertContain affect the failure and success of that assertEqual !!

Answer (score 1):

The error message misleading, but the stacktrace clearly shows the problem happens on the next line (so deleting it makes the test pass)

```
# this is not the function you are looking for
self.assertContains(response.data, serializer_nearby.data)
```

The problem is `assertContains`.  It doesn't do what it sounds like *at all*, it actually checks some things releated to a django response:

```
def assertContains(self, response, text, count=None, status_code=200, msg_prefix='', html=False):
    """
    Assert that a response indicates that some content was retrieved
    successfully, (i.e., the HTTP status code was as expected) and that
    ``text`` occurs ``count`` times in the content of the response.
    If ``count`` is None, the count doesn't matter - the assertion is true
    if the text occurs at least once in the response.
    """
```

This method is so bad that my custom test base throwns an exception if anyone calls it, but I still accidentally do sometimes.  In those cases I really wanted to call `assertIn`.

In your case it looks like you want to compare to `dict` instances for equality.  TestCase has some methods like that, but be aware that they aren't perfect.

```
self.assertDictEqual({"a":1}, {"a":2}) 

# passes, all items in subset are in dictionary
self.assertDictContainsSubset(
    subset={"a": 1},
    dictionary={"z": 2, "a": 2}
)
```